# Reorder Dataframe through transpose and setting values from other columns (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

Given a dataframe:

```
   Location    |    Rate   |   Skill    
San Francisco     $56-$64    architect      
Albany            $43-$50    architect      
San Francisco     $23-$48     tester
```

I'm trying to turn that into this expected result:

```
   Location    |  architect    |   tester   
San Francisco      $56-$64         $23-$48 
Albany             $43-$50
```

I thought about transposing on column `'Skill'` and then setting it's value to the value of `'Rate'` , but I'm not entirely sure how this can be done.

Comment: try to set index based on Location and Skill and get value as rate 
df.set_index(['Location', 'Skill'])['Rate'].unstack()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expect only one row for each `Location-Skill` combination

```
df.groupby(['Location', 'Skill']).first().unstack()
```

Or you can use `pivot`

```
df.pivot(index='Location', columns='Skill', values='Rate')
```

Notice `groupby` will return only the first row of each combination and `pivot` will fail if there is more than one row for any combination.